# Relationship spanning four tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a relationship work that spans four tables. I simplified my code based on the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580649/sqlalchemy-relationships-across-multiple-tables) to match my db.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'))


    # FIXME: This fails with:
    #   "Relationship A.ds could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on
    #    join condition and remote_side arguments.  Consider using the remote() annotation to
    #    accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship."
    #
    # ds = relationship("D", primaryjoin="and_(A.b_id == B.id, B.id == C.b_id, D.id == C.d_id)", viewonly=True)

    def dq(self):
        return sess.query(D).filter(and_(D.id == C.d_id,
                                         C.b_id == B.id,
                                         B.id == A.id,
                                         A.id == self.id))


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'

    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'), primary_key=True)
    d_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('d.id'), primary_key=True)


class D(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'd'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

sess = Session(e)

sess.add(D(id=1))
sess.add(D(id=2))
sess.add(B(id=1))
sess.add(C(b_id=1, d_id=1))
sess.add(C(b_id=1, d_id=2))
sess.add(A(id=1, b_id=1))
sess.flush()


a1 = sess.query(A).first()
print a1.dq().all()
#print a1.ds
```

so my problem is the syntax for the join for the 'ds' relationship. The current error mentions adding remote(), but I have not gotten it to work. I also tried using secondaryjoin without luck. The query in 'dq' work and I was eventually able to work around it by using filters in my code - still I am curious how to construct the relathioship if possible ?

Comment: I see some similar questions but they have no comments or answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28267892 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/18345154.

Answer (score 6):

I'm no sqlalchemy expert, and here's my understanding.

I think the main source of confusion in the sqlalchemy's relationship API is, what do the parameters `primaryjoin`, `secondary`, `secondaryjoin` really mean. To me, here they are:

```
        primaryjoin              secondaryjoin(optional)
source -------------> secondary -------------------------> dest
 (A)                                                        (D)
```

Now we need to figure out what the intermediate parts should be. Despite the fact that custom joins in sqlalchemy is unexpectedly complicated, you do need to understand what you're asking for, that is, the raw SQL. One possible solution is:

```
SELECT a.*, d.id 
FROM a JOIN (b JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id JOIN d ON d.id = c.d_id) /* secondary */
ON a.b_id = b.id /* primaryjoin */ 
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

In this case the source `a` joins with the "secondary" `(b JOIN c .. JOIN d ..)`, and there's no secondary join to `D` since it's already in the `secondary`. We have

```
ds1 = relationship(
    'D',
    primaryjoin='A.b_id == B.id',
    secondary='join(B, C, B.id == C.b_id).join(D, C.d_id == D.id)',
    viewonly=True,  # almost always a better to add this
)
```

Another solution might be:

```
SELECT a.*, d.id 
FROM a JOIN (b JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id) /* secondary */
ON a.b_id = b.id /* primaryjoin */
JOIN d ON c.d_id = d.id /* secondaryjoin */
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

Here `a` joins the secondary `(b JOIN c..)`, and the secondary joins `d` with `c.d_id = d.id`, thus:

```
ds2 = relationship(
    'D',
    primaryjoin='A.b_id == B.id',
    secondary='join(B, C, B.id == C.b_id)',
    secondaryjoin='C.d_id == D.id',
    viewonly=True,  # almost always a better to add this
)
```

The rule of thumb is you put long join paths in the secondary, and link it to the source and dest.

Performance-wise, `ds1` and `ds2` leads to slightly simpler query plan than `dq`, but I don't think there's much difference between them. The planner always knows better.

Here's the updated code for your reference. Note how you can eagerly load the relationship with `sess.query(A).options(joinedload('ds1'))`:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'))

    ds1 = relationship(
        'D',
        primaryjoin='A.b_id == B.id',
        secondary='join(B, C, B.id == C.b_id).join(D, C.d_id == D.id)',
        viewonly=True,  # almost always a better to add this
    )
    ds2 = relationship(
        'D',
        secondary='join(B, C, B.id == C.b_id)',
        primaryjoin='A.b_id == B.id',
        secondaryjoin='C.d_id == D.id',
        viewonly=True,  # almost always a better to add this
    )

    def dq(self):
        return sess.query(D).filter(and_(D.id == C.d_id,
                                         C.b_id == B.id,
                                         B.id == A.id,
                                         A.id == self.id))


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'

    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'), primary_key=True)
    d_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('d.id'), primary_key=True)


class D(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'd'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.id)


e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(e)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

sess = Session(e)

sess.add(D(id=1))
sess.add(D(id=2))
sess.add(B(id=1))
sess.add(B(id=2))
sess.flush()
sess.add(C(b_id=1, d_id=1))
sess.add(C(b_id=1, d_id=2))
sess.add(A(id=1, b_id=1))
sess.add(A(id=2, b_id=2))
sess.commit()


def get_ids(ds):
    return {d.id for d in ds}


a1 = sess.query(A).options(joinedload('ds1')).filter_by(id=1).first()
print('{} a1.ds1: {}'.format('=' * 30, a1.ds1))
assert get_ids(a1.dq()) == get_ids(a1.ds1)


a1 = sess.query(A).options(joinedload('ds2')).filter_by(id=1).first()
print('{} a1.ds2: {}'.format('=' * 30, a1.ds2))
assert get_ids(a1.dq()) == get_ids(a1.ds2)

a2 = sess.query(A).options(joinedload('ds2')).filter_by(id=2).first()
print('{} a2.ds1: {}; a2.ds2 {};'.format('=' * 30, a2.ds1, a2.ds2))
assert a2.ds1 == a2.ds2 == []
```

Answer (score 0):

For your query you need to join your tables together. ie:

```
def db(self);
    return sess.query(D).join(B).filter(...)
```

I'm unsure if you can do multiple joins, but I don't see why not. A good reference to object relational query can be found here:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects

Comment: With a query on the session it works fine with joins.  The problem i have is the relationship.  I am using many relationships with two and three tables which works fine.